# Generate passes are not loading

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, passbook

I am creating a React app that generates IOS passes and sends them to the user either by email or SMS. I'm using the [passbook](https://github.com/frozon/passbook) gem to generate the passes. However, when I try to open them from IOS or the simulator the wallet opens but then the pass does not.

I've checked over the setup instructors and can't see anything I'm missing.

```
# config/intitalize/passbook.rb
Passbook.configure do |passbook|
  passbook.p12_password = '12345'
  passbook.p12_key = Rails.root.join('certificates/passkey.pem')
  passbook.p12_certificate = Rails.root.join('certificates/passcertificate.pem')
  passbook.wwdc_cert = Rails.root.join('certificates/WWDR.pem')
end

# passes_controller.rb
class PassesController < ApplicationController
  def generate
    user_card = UserCard.find_by_hash_id params[:user_card_id]
    pass = user_card.generate_pass
    send_file pass.path, type: 'application/vnd.apple.pkpass', disposition: 'attachment', filename: "pass.pkpass" 
  end
end

# models/user_card.rb
...
  def generate_pass
    data = {
      formatVersion: 1,
      passTypeIdentifier: "pass.com.example.stampcard",
      serialNumber: "TIC1000000518",
      teamIdentifier: ENV['APPLE_TEAM_ID'],
      organizationName: self.card.organization.name,
      description: self.card.desc,
      barcode: {
        message: self.hash_id,
        format: "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",
        messageEncoding: "iso-8859-1",
        altText: self.hash_id
      }
    }
    pass = Passbook::PKPass.new data.to_json.to_s
    pass.addFiles ['logo.png', 'logo@2x.png', 'icon.png', 'icon@2x.png']
    pass.file
  end
...
```

I get the next two files after unzipping the pass.pkpass plus logo.png |  logo@2x.png | icon.png | icon@2x.png

pass.json

```
{"formatVersion":1,"passTypeIdentifier":"pass.com.example.pass","serialNumber":"001","teamIdentifier":"KMCYP92B9M","organizationName":"Douglas, Dibbert and Reynolds","description":"facilitate robust solutions","barcode":{"message":"BInPV506nXdH","format":"PKBarcodeFormatPDF417","messageEncoding":"iso-8859-1"},"coupon":{"primaryFields":[{"key":"offer","label":"for you","value":"Free hug"}]}}
```

manifest.json

```
{"pass.json":"1292e22d5bea9edc79f37115fa680f7c4452a4ec","logo.png":"50a2b2fa88be143902527556d0cde943ce887028","logo@2x.png":"50a2b2fa88be143902527556d0cde943ce887028","icon.png":"50a2b2fa88be143902527556d0cde943ce887028","icon@2x.png":"50a2b2fa88be143902527556d0cde943ce887028"}
```

Comment: Are you using that exact same code above, or are you replacing the placeholders with your own certificate and team name information?

Comment: Yep, the code above is pulling in the certificates and team information dynamically.

Comment: Could you post a link to a .pkpass bundle?  It’s unclear what you mean by “the wallet opens but the pass doesn’t”.  The bundle may be fine but the react code may be wrong, or it could be that there is a problem with the bundle.

Comment: I have added the two JSON files included in the bundle above. What I mean by the "wallet opens but the pass doesn't" is that when I drag pkpass into the IOS simulator the Wallet app opens but the pass never gets shown.

Comment: It looks ok - when you try add to wallet, what error logs do you see in the console?  If the console doesn’t tell you what is wrong or if it says that the trust chain could not be verified, then a link to a .pkpass bundle would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got this working. I know it's not the most satisfying answer but I was able to resolve this by regenerating the certificates. On top of that I realized the serial number was wrong as I was not using a hashed value